# Is this an error in Loomis and Sternberg?

Tags: linear-algebra, norms, errata

In Loomis and Sternberg's *Advanced Calculus* section 3.3 Continuity, they make this comment (just before Theorem 3.2, [pp. [128](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=aDA8DQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA128)-[129](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=aDA8DQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA129) in my copy):

> A linear map $T : V \rightarrow W$ is *bounded below* by $b$ if $\|T(\xi)\| \geq b \|\xi\|$ for all $\xi$ in $V$ [...] If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then it is true, conversely, that if $T$ is bounded below, then it is invertible (why?), but in general this does not follow.

The statement that is followed by "(why?)" seems to me it must be false. For example, the inclusion $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear map bounded below (with $b = 1$), but it is not invertible.

Perhaps they mean $T$ is invertible considered as a map $V \rightarrow \mathrm{im}\ T$? But in this case, the result holds for infinite-dimensional vector spaces too. (A linear map bounded below must have trivial kernel, and so be injective.)

Is this a mistake in the book, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You are correct about all of this. But if you change $W$ to $V$ then it becomes sensible, true in finite dimensions, and false in infinite dimensions, so I think that must be what they meant.